# What does out[i] = *(a_mat + i) do in C?

Tags: c

```
while( i < a_rows * a_cols ) {
    out[i] = *(a_mat + i);  // this line
    i++;
}
```

What does the marked line do?

Comment: Why was this closed? How in the world could "What does the marked line do?" not be a real question? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I agree with @sbi. "Beginner question" != "Not a real question."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It gets the value of whatever is pointed to by `a_mat + i`. It could have been written `a_mat[i]` instead.

Comment: Well, as long as a_mat is declared as an array and whatever it holds has a `sizeof` of 1 byte.

Comment: No, `a_mat[i]` and `*(a_mat + i)` are equivalent in all cases because that's how the indexing operator is defined.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley Adding 1 to a pointer of type int* will increase the pointer of 4 bytes instead of just one. So *(a_mat + i) is perfectly equivalent to a_mat[i].

Comment: @Ben: ...at least on platforms where `sizeof(int)==4`.

Comment: ... Well, now perhaps I know why I had troubles with C.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `x[i]` is the same expression as `*(x + i)`, because adding an integer to a pointer is done by scaling the integer by the size of the pointed-to object, and because it's defined that way.

This means that despite its asymmetrical appearance, the indexing operator `[]` in C is commutative.

The traditional demonstration of this is something like:

```
main() {
  int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        printf("%d\n", x[2]);
        printf("%d\n", 2[x]);
}
```

Both lines are equivalent and print the same thing.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `x[2] == 2[x]` - it's my favorite part of the C language, because it seems unintuitive at first, but after you understand the reasons it makes perfect sense and has a very mathematical symmetry to it.